# MySQL GROUP BY as well as ORDER BY troubles

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

With all the examples here and elsewhere I'm pretty bummed I cannot get this. I'm trying to GROUP BY and ORDER BY (without dups) on the following query.

```
SELECT 
    users.*, user_profile_status.*, photos.*, general.*, 
    experience.*, flagged.*, positions.*, users.user_id AS userID, 
    user_profile_status.user_id AS profileID
FROM users
    LEFT OUTER JOIN user_profile_status ON users.user_id = user_profile_status.user_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN photos ON users.user_id = photos.user_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN general ON users.user_id = general.user_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN experience ON users.user_id = experience.user_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN flagged ON users.user_id = flagged.user_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN positions ON users.user_id = positions.user_id
WHERE 
    users.admin_level = 0
```

I get expected results with ORDER BY or GROUP BY but not both. Both returns 0 rows which should not be the case. The following returns all expected rows 60+.

```
SELECT 
    users.*, user_profile_status.*, photos.*, general.*, 
    experience.*, flagged.*, positions.*, users.user_id AS userID, 
    user_profile_status.user_id AS profileID
FROM users
    LEFT OUTER JOIN user_profile_status ON users.user_id = user_profile_status.user_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN photos ON users.user_id = photos.user_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN general ON users.user_id = general.user_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN experience ON users.user_id = experience.user_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN flagged ON users.user_id = flagged.user_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN positions ON users.user_id = positions.user_id
WHERE 
    users.admin_level = 0
    GROUP BY user_profile_status.user_id
```

When I add ORDER BY to the end, 0 rows are returned.

```
    ORDER BY users.last_login DESC
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10dea/8/0

Comment: Your question currently represents the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Explain the real task, using domain terms. Otherwise - just take those 2 clauses and put it to your query.

Comment: My 2nd query was showing my attempt at the real task. When I place them both in I get 0 results. Without `ORDER BY` results are correct

Comment: You get 0 rows. Okay. So? 0 rows is not an error or issue by itself.

Comment: Without `ORDER BY` I get the expected output, let's say 60 rows. With it, 0. The selection within ORDER BY `users.last_login` has a matching value for each so that is not the problem

Comment: I can use 1 or the other, not both

Comment: "Without ORDER BY I get the expected output, let's say 60 rows. With it, 0" --- it's not possible. `ORDER BY` cannot reduce number of rows in result set. And it still does not shed any light on your real problem.

Comment: That's exactly what is happening. I tack on `ORDER BY users.last_login DESC` and it returns 0 rows.

Comment: Well, that's what is happening. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Something else is happening. What you're saying in the last 2 comments is impossible for *any* ANSI SQL-compilant RDBMS.

Comment: In your query there is no table `users` but you refer to it multiple times, so the whole query is broken. It's impossible the whole query executed without errors.

Comment: I wish that wasn't the case. With `ORDER BY ss_users.last_login DESC` 67 rows are returned. With `GROUP BY user_profile_status.user_id` 67 rows are returned. With BOTH, 0 rows are returned.

Comment: Please reproduce it on http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: "In your query there is no table users but you refer to it multiple times, so the whole query is broken. It's impossible the whole query executed without errors.' There is. I was trying to remove the prefix to make reading it easier. I simply missed one.

Comment: Pro tip: never use `SELECT *` or any variant of it in software unless you know exactly why you're doing that. Especially in joined tables, `SELECT *` puts out lots of redundant and pointless columns in the result set.  Pro tip: don't use the pernicious nonstandard MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`.  Read this. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html . Please consider rewriting your queries taking these suggestions. They'll be easier for you, and us on SO, to understand.  Seriously.

Comment: Thanks. Are you suggesting that even if I need all columns I should name them rather than using *? What would be the benefit?

Comment: @zerkms http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10dea/8/0  So it looks like it's working with `ORDER BY` at the end. If `ORDER BY` is placed before `GROUP BY` That's where I was getting my error

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was placing ORDER BY before GROUP BY -- which I stated incorrectly in my question. This caused an error. The following, with ORDER BY at the end worked.
So future note to self. ORDER BY after GROUP BY.

```
SELECT 
    users.*, user_profile_status.*, photos.*, general.*, 
    experience.*, flagged.*, positions.*, users.user_id AS userID, 
    user_profile_status.user_id AS profileID
FROM users
    LEFT OUTER JOIN user_profile_status ON users.user_id = user_profile_status.user_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN photos ON users.user_id = photos.user_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN general ON users.user_id = general.user_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN experience ON users.user_id = experience.user_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN flagged ON users.user_id = flagged.user_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN positions ON users.user_id = positions.user_id
WHERE 
    users.admin_level = 0
    GROUP BY user_profile_status.user_id 
    ORDER BY users.last_login DESC
```

Comment: "So future note to self. ORDER BY after GROUP BY." --- it must be another not actually: turn on error reporting in development production. Then you would know that on the first run.